# Error: cannot find symbol class + variable

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I got two errors using SharedPreferences in Android Studio:

error: cannot find symbol variable pref

error: cannot find symbol class Editor

I was trying to make it save the question added to a SharedPreference and then retrieve it when it comes back to the activity.

I mainly copied my code from websites, so that's probably part of the issue.

My code:

```
package com.example.sylvie.dogwise;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Questions extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listview;
    String[] ListElements = new String[]{
            "How much food should I feed my dog?",
            "How do I teach my dog to sit?"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.QuestionsList);

        final List<String> ListElementsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ListElements));
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (Questions.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ListElementsArrayList);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        String newquestion=pref.getString("key_question", null);
        ListElementsArrayList.add(newquestion);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Bundle newQuestion = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (newQuestion == null) {
            return;
        }
        final String QuestionName = newQuestion.getString("QuestionName");

        ListElementsArrayList.add(QuestionName);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("key_question", QuestionName);
        editor.commit();

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Question_1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Question_2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0 );
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Question_Asked.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("QuestionTitle", QuestionName);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ;

    public void backHomeOnClick(View view) {
        Intent b = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(b);
    }

    public void askAQuestionOnClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AskAQuestion.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    ;
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use it correctly -

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("key_question", QUESTION_NAME);

editor.apply();
```

And you need to move the Shared pref declaration above your pref.getString call otherwise it will not be able to detect pref.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
String newquestion=pref.getString("key_question", null);
```

Comment: I asked for removal because at this stage of the code it doesn't look like he/she needs to get the shared pref as the first step. He is trying to save the data here.

Comment: Yup makes sense. Missed that part.